# Invalid hook call. when try to connect hocs with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to create react Hoc as functional component to check authenticated users,
I don't want to use local storage so i am using `redux-persist` to save the token
this is what I did

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default Component => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { token } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  return token ? <Component /> : history.push('/login');
};
```

I got this error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: `export default Component => {` - this is not valid syntax

Comment: even if id ```export const WithAuth = Component => { }```
it does't work

Comment: share us where you use this hook

Comment: import { WithAuth } from '../Hocs/WithAuth';

import Login from '../Pages/Login';
import SignUp from '../Pages/SignUp';
import Home from '../Pages/Home';

export default [
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: Login,
    exact: true
  },
  {
    path: '/signup',
    component: SignUp,
    exact: false
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    component: WithAuth(Home),
    exact: false
  }
];